# How to verify if a SQL Account is still used?

Tags: sql-server

We have a SQL Server Login on a SQL Server 2008, and no one seems to know if the account is actually being used or not. It is assumed it is being used, as it is configured in a `Linked_Server` connection, however no one knows if it is still really being used, and if so for what. How do we verify, aside from disabling and waiting for a squeal?

Comment: SQL Server Trace/Profiler or Extended Events session.

Comment: Turn it off and see who complains? (Note - may not be a great career move)

Comment: It's not that unreasonable Greg  Large companies will allow it after you've done basic due diligence with a trace, raise a change record with a rollback plan, and it survives the review process.

Answer (score 3):

An additional, easy, option is to log all successful & failed logins.  Under the server properties tab

[image]

This will write any use (or attempted use) of the login to the SQL Server log.  From there you can [programatically search the log](https://sqlstudies.com/2015/08/17/pulling-data-from-the-error-log/).

```
USE Test
GO

-- P1 is the file number starting at 0
DECLARE 
@p2 INT = 1, 
-- P2 1 for SQL logs, 2 for SQL Agent logs
@p3 NVARCHAR(255) = 'UserName', 
-- P3 is a value to search on
@p4 NVARCHAR(255) = ''
-- P4 is another search value


IF OBJECT_ID('IOErrorLog') IS NULL
    CREATE TABLE IOErrorLog (
            ServerName nvarchar(256), 
            LogFileName nvarchar(4000),
            Occurances int,
            LogDate datetime,
            ProcessInfo nvarchar(50),
            ErrorText nvarchar(max),
        CONSTRAINT pk_IOErrorLog PRIMARY KEY (ServerName, LogDate, LogFileName)
    )

----------------------------------------------------------------------
-- This part of the code was found here: 
-- https://ask.sqlservercentral.com/questions/99484/number-of-error-log-files.html

DECLARE @FileList AS TABLE (
    subdirectory NVARCHAR(4000) NOT NULL
    ,DEPTH BIGINT NOT NULL
    ,[FILE] BIGINT NOT NULL
);

DECLARE @ErrorLog NVARCHAR(4000), @ErrorLogPath NVARCHAR(4000);
SELECT @ErrorLog = CAST(SERVERPROPERTY(N'errorlogfilename') AS NVARCHAR(4000));
SELECT @ErrorLogPath = SUBSTRING(@ErrorLog, 1, LEN(@ErrorLog) - CHARINDEX(N'\', REVERSE(@ErrorLog))) + N'\';

INSERT INTO @FileList
EXEC xp_dirtree @ErrorLogPath, 0, 1;

DECLARE @NumberOfLogfiles INT;
SET @NumberOfLogfiles = (SELECT COUNT(*) FROM @FileList WHERE [@FileList].subdirectory LIKE N'ERRORLOG%');
-- SELECT @NumberOfLogfiles;
----------------------------------------------------------------------

CREATE TABLE #temp (
    LogDate datetime, 
    ProcessInfo nvarchar(500), 
    ErrorText nvarchar(max))

DECLARE @p1 INT = 0

WHILE @p1 < @NumberOfLogfiles
BEGIN

BEGIN TRY
    INSERT INTO #temp 
    EXEC sys.xp_readerrorlog @p1,@p2,@p3,@p4 
END TRY
BEGIN CATCH
    PRINT 'Error occurred processing file ' + cast(@p1 as varchar(10))
END CATCH

SET @p1 = @p1 + 1
END

INSERT INTO IOErrorLog
    SELECT DISTINCT @@SERVERNAME, 
        SUBSTRING(ErrorText,charindex('[',ErrorText)+1, 
            charindex(']',ErrorText)-charindex('[',ErrorText)-1), 
        SUBSTRING(ErrorText, 27, patindex('%occurrence%',ErrorText)-28),
        LogDate, ProcessInfo, ErrorText
    FROM #temp
    WHERE #temp.LogDate NOT IN (
        SELECT LogDate
        FROM IOErrorLog
        WHERE ServerName = @@SERVERNAME)

DROP TABLE #temp

SELECT * FROM IOErrorLog
```

The down side here is that you are logging the login successes & failures for everyone.  It could bloat your error log a bit.  It's generally considered a best practice to pull at least the failed logins though.

Answer (score 1):

There are multiple ways to achieve this.

1. Through tracing (profiler trace or extended events)
2. Using logon triggers https://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/bb326598.aspx
3. Another approach would be to disable the login. If somebody will yell, than you will know that it is still in use.
   ALTER LOGIN [mylogin] DISABLE
   GO

There are some dmvs where you can get an idea about if it is in use:
SELECT * FROM sys.syslogins contains the datetime when the account was last updated. There is also a column which tells you when the login was last accessed. Bu the last accessed column is "Identified for informational purposes only. Not supported. Future compatibility is not guaranteed." (https://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/ms178593(v=sql.120).aspx). In SQL Server 2014 this date is not being updated during login (most probably this will work only for SQL Server 2000). The new sys.server_principals-DMV does not contains such information anymore.